# Error when inheriting from a template class with multiple parameters

Tags: c++

**Goal**: To inherit from a class with 2 template parameters.

**Error**

> Error error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'

**The Code**

```
template< typename Type >
class AssetManager : public IsDerivedFromBase< Type, Asset* >
{
    // Class specific code here
};
```

**Things you need to know:** Asset is a class that just wraps a `char*` with a getter/setter and `IsDerivedFromBase` will be used to basically test wether or not `Type` is a derivative of `Asset`. These sets of classes are isolated in there own small scale visual Studio 2012 project and will be integrated into the main project once all the functionality has been tested thoroughly.

**Some Edits based on Comments**

Thank you for the help so far, I really appreciate it. Here are some more specifics:

*IsDerivedFromBase.h*

```
#ifndef ISDERIVEDFROMBASE_H
#define ISDERIVEDFROMBASE_H

#include< iostream > // For access to NULL

namespace Fenrir
{
    template< typename Type, typename Base >
    class IsDerivedFromBase
    {
    private:
        static void Constraints( Type* _inheritedType )
        {
            Base* temp = NULL;

            // Should throw compiler error if
            // this assignment is not possible.
            temp = _inheritedType;
        }

    protected:
        IsDerivedFromBase( ) { void( *test )( Type* ) = Constraints; }
    };
}

#endif
```

*Note*: This class was based off of a class I read about in an article. I have since found a better way to achieve the desired result; however, I wish to understand where this error is stemming from.

*AssetManager.h"*

```
#ifndef ASSETMANAGER_H
#define ASSETMANAGER_H

#include "IsDerivedFromBase.h"

namespace Fenrir
{
    template< typename Type >
    class AssetManager : public IsDerivedFromBase< Type, Asset* >
    {
        // Class specific code
    };
}

#endif
```

Keeping *class specific code* to a minimum to keep this post as neat as possible, if more info is needed just let me know and I can add it in :).

Comment: What is the declaration of `IsDerivedFromBase`?

Comment: Provide a self-contained, minimal example that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Seems like compiler doesn't know about IsDerivedFromBase class, or about it is template class. Anyway, there are other errors, that compiler gives you. Look at they.

Comment: I have added some more information. The error listed in the post is the only one I am getting, so I have no other clues to go off of at this point. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @Marc: The compiler doesn't know what `Asset` is, where do you define the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue which was interestingly silly. So due to a comment (from Jesse Good) I took a quick look at my includes. Since this was a small "whip it up quick" kind of project I didn't really pay much attention to them. I don't know exactly where the error was occuring, but I found out that *AssetManager* did not know about *IsDerivedFromBase* so I set up the following code block to just solve that issue without having to write a bunch of
*#include* statements everywhere!

```
// Contact point houses all of the include files
// for this project to keep everything in one place.

#ifndef CONTACTPOINT_H
#define CONTACTPOINT_H

#include "Asset.h"
#include "Sprite.h" 
#include "IsDerivedFromBase.h"
#include "GenericManager.h"
#include "AssetManager.h"   

#endif
```

Now I just include this in every header and all is well. I've been programming C++ for a little over a year now and never ran into this, a good lesson to learn for anyone new programming.

Thanks for your help everyone : )

Answer (score 0):

That error message is common when the compiler encounters an identifier that it did not expect, so a first guess would be that `IsDerivedFromBase` is not *known* to the compiler at the time (maybe you did not include the appropriate header?). Alternatively, if `IsDerivedFromBase` is not a template, the compiler would also expect a `,`  (or `;`) after it.